# No C terminal on furnace to connect a wifi thermostat

Tags: electrical, thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I have an new Emerson thermostat and would like to connect a c wire so it always has power. I have an extra wire that's not being used, but I don't have a C wire terminal on my furnace. I'm wondering if I can use any of the unused terminals or if I can tap into one of the wires coming off of the 24v transformer.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The blue wire coming off of the transformer is what you want, but there might be a better place to tie into that.  Look for any wires that are simply screwed to the metal chassis of the air handler.  You can check with a continuity tester, but those chassis grounds are usually a connection for that other side of the transformer (the blue wire).

Looking at that schematic, I can see a few places where a wire terminates to "ground", but I don't necessarily see any terminals where the "C wire" would be conveniently exposed.  Also, when you find a ground screw use a volt meter to make sure you get a good 24v there between the ground point and the red wire from the thermostat and/or transformer.

Comment: Lol I think I edited your answer instead of mine.

Comment: The B terminal already has a green wire on it. Can I just add another wire to that terminal? It will be ok?

Answer (score 1):

The B terminal should be you common wire. It looks like you have air conditioning, one wire goes to the Y terminal and the other is common. Often marked B for heat pump applications.

[image]

It's literally the same as the blue wire on the transformer as in JPhi1618 pointed out. Either spot will work the same. The B terminal is easier.

Comment: The B terminal already has a green wire on it. Can I just add another wire to that terminal? It will be ok?

Comment: Fixed the edit...  I believe you about the B wire, but that notation on the schematic is saying to "See note 5" on the right side of the label.  The 5 being under the O and the B terminal is coincidence.

Comment: There is a rectangle box on the left above all the text that lists "B/C" as a notation for Common, so makes sense.  Voltage and continuity test can confirm if there is and doubt.  And @Karl, yes, two of the same size wires under that screw terminal is fine - typically one on each side.  One wire being larger than the other can cause clamping issues on some terminals.

Comment: You guys are awesome.  I'll try the B terminal tonight and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I finally got time to do this yesterday and it worked beautifully. Thanks again!